# JSON Object to String

Tags: jquery, json

How can I take a JSON object and convert it back into the original string format?

Thanks

Answer (score 14):

You could use an excelent **json2.js** library:  https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Check out the `JSON.stringify` method.

**Edit:**

It seems like the librabry moved to github repo now: https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js

Answer (score 5):

Use the stringify method from Douglas Crockford's JSON object:

http://www.json.org/js.html

This will show your object in an alert box:

```
alert(JSON.stringify(myObject));
```

Comment: Why would you need jquery support? After all it's pure javascript.

Comment: the JSON library is not part of jQuery, but it is very useful.  I highly recommend using it.

Comment: JSON is included natively in most modern browsers now!

Answer (score 1):

There are a few jQuery plugins to do this. [jQuery-json](http://code.google.com/p/jquery-json/) is one of them, which I've tried successfully.

Answer (score 1):

when it's an object, it's a javascript object, then it gets encoded as a string, a string that is a javascript syntax that expresses the object json-encoded. (`JSON: JavaScript Object Notation`).

However, these are the jquery built in function to parse json is `jQuery.getJSON` (retrieves the object out of the string).

to do things the other way around check this: [Serializing to JSON in jQuery](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/191881/serializing-to-json-in-jquery)